# How to create Tabs using Android Xamarin with MvvmCross MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement a tabs control of ViewPager inside the android project of a MVVMCross xamarin solution. The binding is working in the windows phone app so i assume the Viewmodel is working.

I have an activity that inherits MvxTabsFragmentActivity that i want to add Tabs into. My app can not detect the id :  Resource.Id.actualtabcontent.

This is how i Attempted it, (https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings/blob/master/Bindings.Droid/BindableViewPager.cs)
as well as attempting this 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid

Does anyone have any idea about how we can solve this?

basically we have a parent viewmodel with a collection of LIst inside of it, but we are struggling to get the binding to work inside of android. we have tried even creating a new app with just the tabs in it, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use MvxTabsFragmentActivity as it is a bit outdated. This sample is the latest available: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Your layout should be something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        local:tabGravity="center"
        local:tabMode="scrollable" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The TabLayout makes the tabs for you.

Comment: I can't seem to add the packages. This is the error i get : Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 4.0.0-beta2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding (≥ 4.0.0-beta2)'.
Downloading Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView 4.0.0-beta2...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries (≥ 4.0.0-beta2)'.
Downloading MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta2...
'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries' already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore'.

Comment: Explained here: http://mvvmcross.com/SecondBetaRelease/ and here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1088#issuecomment-130408367 to fix it.

Comment: the updated link is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments