# Instagram like app with mvvmcross and xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

A few years ago I created an app like Instagram with mvvmcross and tabHost, but since that is now obsolete, How should I go about doing this? I am assuming nested fragments but I get tripped up in how to create a presenter for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this answer from Martin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353441/how-to-create-tabs-using-android-xamarin-with-mvvmcross-mvxtabsfragmentactivity

Comment: What do you mean get tripped up? Did you try to start creating a custom presenter? Would you mind sharing that presenter so people can help you?